# How to Change WooCommerce "Create an account" Text?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm facing a problem to change the "Create an account" text on the checkout page of woocommerce. I searched on Google but didn't find any result. How to modify the text?

[image: create an account woocommerce]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to modify the template you can use a filter to change the text.  Copy and paste into your theme's functions.php file.  It's a much cleaner solution as template files may need updating in the future.

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if ( 'woocommerce' !== $domain ) {
        return $translated_text;
    }
    
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Create an account?' :
            $translated_text = __( 'This is the new text that will be displayed!', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Comment: Brilliant, I tried to add HTML using this, but that is getting stripped out. Any solution?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I didn't think it stripped the HTML but maybe there's something in your theme removing it.

Comment: This does not work with newest wordpress anymore

Comment: Seems to be formatted incorrectly. Casuing PHP validation errors, and crashes site.

Comment: @BillBronson interesting, I don't see any changes to "\checkout\form-billing.php" template so I would assume it should still work in the latest 7.01 WooCommerce version.  Theme templates can override this so maybe that's the issue...

Answer (score -1):

Though there are no hooks to modify this text but there is an another option. Copy and overwrite the woocommerce/template/form-billing.php template into your theme and modify the text there.

Steps to follow

1. copy form-billing.php file
2. go to your activated theme folder
3. create a new woocommerce folder
4. paste the file there
5. edit the text present on line 61 - Create an account?  to whatever text you want

Comment: Please refer to my solution above there is a filter available.